# MongoDB's geospatial index: how fast is it?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, geospatial

I'm doing a `where in box` query on a collection of ~40K documents. The query takes ~0.3s and fetching documents takes ~0.6 seconds (there are ~10K documents in the result set).

The documents are fairly small (~100 bytes each) and I limit the result to return the lat/lon only.

It seems *very* slow. Is this about right or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi Pawel! Have you tried .explain() (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization#Optimization-Explain) on your query?

Comment: I have.

    {u'allPlans': [{u'cursor': u'GeoBrowse-box', u'indexBounds': {}}], u'cursor': u'GeoBrowse-box', u'indexBounds': {}, u'millis': 278, u'n': 10479, u'nscanned': 10479, u'nscannedObjects': 10479, u'oldPlan': {u'cursor': u'GeoBrowse-box', u'indexBounds': {}}}

No idea what it means.

Comment: so ... your cursor type - is GeoBrowse-box - because you use $box query. scanining collection using index because nscanned is 10K not 40K. can you show collection .stats()?

Comment: Thanks! Collection's stats: {
    "ns" : "test.latlon",
    "count" : 39324,
    "size" : 6662728,
    "avgObjSize" : 169.4315939375445,
    "storageSize" : 14327040,
    "numExtents" : 6,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 10747904,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "flags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 5136384,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 2244608,
        "location__date_1_stat_map_id_1" : 2891776
    },
    "ok" : 1
}

Comment: Just did a test using regular index and querying: x < lat < y and x1 < lon < x2. Surprisingly it's 3x faster than using geospatial index. What's its use then?

Comment: Hi Pawel! Is there any news? have you try 1.7.x branch?

Comment: I also have the same issue. My query on collction of 10k docs using 'geospatial index' takes over 0.1 seconds. "Explain" shows: "ncanned 3100, n: 46"

Answer (score 1):

It seems very slow indeed. A roughly equivalent search on I did on PostgreSQL, for example, is almost too fast to measure (i.e. probably faster than 1ms).

I don't know much about MongoDB, but are you certain that the geospatial index is actually turned on? (I ask because in RDBMSs it's easy to define a table with geometrical/geographical columns yet not define the actual indexing appropriately, and so you get roughly the same performance as what you describe).